# How do I search a list of booleans for the first true?

Tags: kdb

I'm trying to find the index of the first true value:

```
1b?001b

Expected result: 2
Actual result: ,0b
```

Two questions:

- How do I solve this issue?
- What is my code actually doing?

Comment: What approaches have you researched so far?

Comment: Well I put my best attempt up above. I've checked against the documentation, which does not explicitly define `?` for booleans, however I would have expected it to work, based on normal KDB semantics. The docs I'm referencing are here: https://code.kx.com/q/ref/find/

Comment: A little more messing around with it suggests KDB is interpreting it as a binary integer, not as a list of booleans...

Comment: @Martin Actually, I think it's interpreting this as a roll, rather than a find.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your first question, you want to use the `where` keyword, which when passed a boolean list will return the indices of the true values:

```
q)where 00101b
2 4
```

Use `first` in front of the above to obtain what you want.

For your second question, I believe q is casting the left argument of to an int/long and then 'rolling' on the right argument list (see https://code.kx.com/q/ref/deal/).

Example:

```
q)0b?111b
`boolean$() //return 0 random elements from 111b
q)1b?111b
,1b //return 1 random element from 111b
```

Answer (score 5):

In addition to @Kylebonnes answer, if you still wish to use the "?" find operator, it is possible to do so:

```
q)001b?1b
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Find](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/find/), as @xxPJFxx does, means the search stops at the first hit, where `where` locates all the hits:

```
q)show L:1000000?0b
101001111111001110100001110101011011010000101001010110010110111010000010000100000000100..
q)\ts:1000 first where L
396 4194512
q)\ts:1000 L?1b
0 704
```

Earlier answers to your second question are correct: you have found an undocumented edge case of the [Roll](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/deal/) operator, which takes an integer left argument. I’ll check with the implementors and update the documentation if boolean left args are also supported.

The [Overloaded glyphs](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/overloads/) page can help you identify which operator a glyph denotes.